# Corsair lighting hubs are disabling my SSDs

Tags: ssd, sata, rgb, corsair

I have a new PC build that I've been having some issues with regarding my SSDs not being recognized.

Here are my PC specs for reference:

- **Chassis:** Phanteks Eclipse P360A
- **Motherboard:** Gigabyte B550 Aorus Elite V2
- **CPU:** AMD Ryzen 7 5800X
- **CPU Cooler:** Corsair H100i RGB AIO (240mm radiator)
- **Power Supply:** Corsair RM750x 750W Gold Certified
- **RAM:** 16GB (2x8GB) Corsair Vengeance RGB Pro DDR4 3600
- **GPU:** NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti *(yes, it's old; thanks COVID)*
- **Storage:**

  - 1x Samsung 970 EVO Plus M.2 2280 (OS drive)
  - 2x Samsung 860 EVO 2.5" 2TB SSD (apps / games)
  - 1x Seagate BarraCuda 4TB 5400 RPM SATA HD (storage)
- **Case Fans:**

  - 5x Corsair LL120 (2 are attached to the H100i radiator)
  - Corsair Lighting Node Pro
  - Corsair RGB Fan Hub

---

After installing the Corsair Lighting Node Pro and RGB Fan Hub, my 2 SSDs are no longer recognized by my BIOS.

At first I thought I may have been overloading my SATA power cable, but after further troubleshooting, I've determined that if either of the two Corsair devices (the LNP or hub) are connected to any SATA power connection, the SSDs will not be recognized.

To confirm this, I disconnected my HDD, both Corsair devices, and one SSD from their SATA cables and booted into my BIOS. The connected SSD was there.

I plugged in just one of the Corsair devices to a separate SATA cable and restarted; the SSD was not recognized again. So it seems if either of those devices is powered at all, the SSDs are not.

**EDIT:** Further testing revealed that the USB from the LNP to my motherboard may also cause the issue now.

I have tried all of the following configurations and none of them allow my SSDs to be used unless all the Corsair devices are disconnected:

[image: graph]

Hot-swapping (plugging in the Corsair devices after my system has booted) doesn't seem to affect the SSDs at all, though the lights on the fans do act very erratic.